# DynamoDB Credential initialization giving Context initialization failed :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a Spring based web application where I need to create connection with DynamoDB. Every time I try to, it is giving Context initialization failed :`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB`.

Here No where I am using AmazonDynamoDB. And I also removed static so that it won't execute before initialization.

My Code is:

```
@Repository
public class AbstractImplDAO <E> implements IAbstractDAO<E> {
  AmazonDynamoDBClient dbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("UserName").getCredentials()).withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
  DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dbClient, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(SaveBehavior.CLOBBER));
  @Override
  public IInfo getData(E entity) {
    return null;
  }
  @Override
  public IInfo add(E entity) {
    InventoryLog e = new InventoryLog();
    e = (InventoryLog) entity;
    mapper.save(e);
    System.out.println("Print Anything");
    IInfo info = new Info();
    info.setStatus(true);
    return info;
  }
  @Override
  public IInfo update(E entity) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Context initialization failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1906) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

My application context is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <task:annotation-driven />


  <context:component-scan base-package="com.rit.randemmiddleware.*" />

  <util:properties id="propertyConfigurer"
                   location="/WEB-INF/configuration/web/WebConfigLocal.properties" />

  <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer"
                                location="/WEB-INF/configuration/Environment.properties,
      /WEB-INF/configuration/db/DbConfigLocal.properties" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
  <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />


  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Please provide solution for this. I am new on this. If possible please help me with an example, so that I can implement DynamoDB in web my application.

Comment: Did you make sure the AWS SDK is being imported correctly? Also try cleaning the project once (I think you might have already done that). AmazonDynamoDB is the interface which is implemented by AmazonDynamoDBClient that you are using.